# ARKit Unity deleting prefabs from scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I have problem with ARKit in Unity. I want to place some GameObjects to plain. Now I can add endless gameobjects. But I have problem with deleting this and I do not know where write script for that. Also I need to use some parts of my Prefab like a 3d buttons and start some code(script). Can you help me please?

Comment: Start with the Unity tutorials on their website and then once you have a basic understanding of how to create an app in Unity do some tutorials on ARKit.